# How to add bootstrap flash messages to entire app via application.html.erb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, ruby-on-rails-6

I've generated some resources via `scaffold`, and see `<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>` at the top of index and show views.

I have searched for all occurrences of this across the app and deleted them (so there are no flash messages).

Then, I added this to `application.html.erb`

```
<% if notice %>
  <p class="alert alert-success"><%= notice %></p>
<% end %>
<% if alert %>
  <p class="alert alert-danger"><%= alert %></p>
<% end %>
```

Will this effectively generate all possible flash messages?

The reason I ask is because I believe [bootstrap has >2 types of messages](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/alerts/#examples) (e.g. "success", "danger", "info", "primary", "secondary", "warning", "light", "dark"), yet the above code seems to only cater to 2.

For reference, the added code comes from [here](https://guides.railsgirls.com/devise)

Answer (score 0):

Devise just uses *notice* and *alert*. If you want more, just add it as described [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Flash/ClassMethods.html). If you add *warning*, like in the docs, you can add:

```
<% if warning %>
  <p class="alert alert-warning"><%= warning %></p>
<% end %>
```

and so on.